# Conversion error when using switch -h-1 in txt file

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, varchar

I've written a windows batch script that downloads inventory from POS system and then uploads it to another file. I've been getting errors during the upload, which I've finally discovered is because of the hyphens being generated in the txt file below the header:

```
sku                quantity
------------------------------
1234                 1
```

I was able to remove the entire header using switch -h-1, but when trying to re-add the header (without hyphens), I'm running into data conversion errors. Please see sql below. The error message reads: "Error converting data type varchar to numeric", line 3

```
set nocount on
SELECT 'sku' AS sku, 'quantity' AS sku
UNION
SELECT  CAST(IM_BARCOD.BARCOD AS VARCHAR(32)) as sku, case when 
IM_INV.QTY_AVAIL > 0 then IM_INV.QTY_AVAIL else CAST(0 AS VARCHAR(32)) END as 
quantity
FROM        IM_BARCOD INNER JOIN IM_INV ON IM_INV.ITEM_NO = IM_BARCOD.ITEM_NO 
INNER JOIN 
        IM_PRC ON IM_INV.ITEM_NO = IM_PRC.ITEM_NO INNER JOIN 
        IM_ITEM ON IM_INV.ITEM_NO = IM_ITEM.ITEM_NO
WHERE   (IM_ITEM.TRK_METH = 'N' AND IM_INV.LOC_ID = 'MAIN')
UNION
SELECT  CAST(IM_BARCOD.BARCOD AS VARCHAR(32)) as sku, case when 
IM_INV_CELL.QTY_AVAIL > 0 then IM_INV_CELL.QTY_AVAIL else CAST(0 AS 
VARCHAR(32)) END as quantity
FROM        IM_BARCOD INNER JOIN IM_PRC ON IM_BARCOD.ITEM_NO = IM_PRC.ITEM_NO 
INNER JOIN 
        IM_INV_CELL ON IM_BARCOD.ITEM_NO = IM_INV_CELL.ITEM_NO AND 
IM_INV_CELL.DIM_1_UPR=IM_BARCOD.DIM_1_UPR AND 
IM_INV_CELL.DIM_2_UPR=IM_BARCOD.DIM_2_UPR AND 
IM_INV_CELL.DIM_3_UPR=IM_BARCOD.DIM_3_UPR INNER JOIN 
        IM_ITEM ON IM_BARCOD.ITEM_NO = IM_ITEM.ITEM_NO
WHERE   (IM_ITEM.TRK_METH = 'G' AND IM_INV_CELL.LOC_ID = 'MAIN')
```

Yet, I'm trying to convert the numeric fields to varchar. Any thoughts? I'm trying this based on another post from stack overflow.

Thank you!

Comment: It's either SQL-Server or MySQL, but not both. Which one are you using.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
case when IM_INV.QTY_AVAIL > 0 then IM_INV.QTY_AVAIL else CAST(0 AS VARCHAR(32)) END
```

You need to cast the `qty_avail` to `varchar(32)` in the `THEN` clause.   Otherwise it will try to implicitly cast that column as a numeric data type.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I've given it a whirl. I'm still getting an error on Line 2, which is essentially the pseudo headers I'm inserting with a  UNION. Any thoughts why that might be?

Comment: @Liz You've aliased both columns as `sku`.   They need to have different aliases.

Comment: Thanks @Tab Alleman. I corrected the column aliases, and also added the CAST statement to the when clause as well as the then clause, which seemed to work. However, the aliases are not appearing as the column headers now. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I would need more detail.  If the aliases aren't appearing, what is?   And where are you seeing this behavior.   A screenshot would help a lot here.

Comment: There's no header at all, the first row is the first line of data. This is what I ended up having to do with the query.... SELECT CAST('sku' as VARCHAR(32)) AS sku, CAST('quantity' as VARCHAR(32)) AS quantity
UNION
SELECT CAST(IM_BARCOD.BARCOD AS VARCHAR(32)) as sku, case when IM_INV.QTY_AVAIL > 0 then CAST(IM_INV.QTY_AVAIL AS VARCHAR(32)) else CAST(0 as VARCHAR(32)) END as quantity
FROM...

Comment: And then this is the batch script file that runs the sql query:@echo off

cd C:\

sqlcmd -S BCEXP-CPSERVER -d BCEXP -i C:\SQL\Amazon\AZ_inventory_download.sql -o C:\SQL\Amazon\amazonmain1.txt -h-1

exit /b

Comment: My only thought is that since you didn't use an ORDER BY, the row containing your headers could be further down in the results, and not the top row.   When you UNION multiple queries, there is no guarantee that the top UNION will be on top of the lower UNION(s) in the results.

Comment: That was it! Thank you!